# Disabling all privileges with AdjustTokenPrivileges using DisableAllPrivileges?

Tags: security, winapi

I am trying to strip a process from all privileges using `AdjustTokenPrivileges` by setting the parameter `DisableAllPrivileges` to `TRUE`:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cwchar>

int main()
{
  auto process = GetCurrentProcess();
  HANDLE primary_token;

  if (OpenProcessToken(process, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &primary_token) == FALSE)
  {
    fwprintf(stderr, L"OpenProcessToken: failed");
  }

  if (AdjustTokenPrivileges(primary_token, TRUE, nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr) == FALSE)
  {
    fwprintf(stderr, L"AdjustTokenPrivileges: failed");
  }

  CloseHandle(primary_token);

  auto event = CreateEventW(nullptr, FALSE, FALSE, nullptr);
  WaitForSingleObject(event, INFINITE);
}
```

It does not seem to working when viewing the process privileges in [Sysinternals Process Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8PxI.png).

I solved it by querying all privileges and changing the attribute to `SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED` but I am not sure why setting `DisableAllPrivileges` to `TRUE` does not work.

Comment: Because I don't see any question mark in your post ... what exactly is your question? Why setting DisableAllPrivileges to TRUE did not work? Why your new solution worked? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It does not seem to working when viewing the process privileges in
>   Sysinternals Process Explorer.

Sysinternals Process Explorer show wrong image. `DisableAllPrivileges` work as excepted - remove [`SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/ns-winnt-_token_privileges) attribute from all privileges in token. but some privileges can also have [`SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/ns-winnt-_token_privileges) attribute. `SeChangeNotifyPrivilege` for example have this attribute. it remain unchanged, what and show your image. but anyway only [`SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/ns-winnt-_token_privileges) attribute used in [`PrivilegeCheck`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-privilegecheck) or [SePrivilegeCheck](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-seprivilegecheck) api. so you really effective disable all privileges in your token, including `SeChangeNotifyPrivilege`. all calls, which require concrete privilege, which have not [`SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/ns-winnt-_token_privileges) attribute in your token - fail, even if [`SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/ns-winnt-_token_privileges) attribute exist.

test code

```
#ifndef RtlPointerToOffset
#define RtlPointerToOffset(B,P) ((ULONG)( ((PCHAR)(P)) - ((PCHAR)(B)) ))
#endif

inline ULONG BOOL_TO_ERROR(BOOL fOk)
{
    return fOk ? NOERROR : GetLastError();
}

volatile UCHAR guz = 0;

void DumpTokenPrivs(HANDLE hToken)
{
    union {
        PVOID buf;
        PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES ptp;
    };

    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

    ULONG cb = 0, rcb = 0x40;

    ULONG dwError;
    do 
    {
        if (cb < rcb)
        {
            cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
        }

        if (NOERROR == (dwError = BOOL_TO_ERROR(
            GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenPrivileges, buf, cb, &rcb))))
        {
            ULONG PrivilegeCount = ptp->PrivilegeCount;

            DbgPrint("PrivilegeCount = %u\n", PrivilegeCount);
            if (PrivilegeCount)
            {
                PLUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES Privileges = ptp->Privileges;
                do 
                {
                    WCHAR Name[64];
                    ULONG cch = RTL_NUMBER_OF(Name);
                    if (!LookupPrivilegeNameW(0, &Privileges->Luid, Name, &cch))
                    {
                        _swprintf(Name, L"{%u-%u}", 
                            Privileges->Luid.HighPart, Privileges->Luid.LowPart);
                    }

                    BOOL fResult;
                    PRIVILEGE_SET ps = { 
                        1, PRIVILEGE_SET_ALL_NECESSARY, { 
                            { Privileges->Luid.LowPart, Privileges->Luid.HighPart } 
                        } 
                    };

                    if (!PrivilegeCheck(hToken, &ps, &fResult))
                    {
                        DbgPrint("PrivilegeCheck=%u\n", GetLastError());
                    }

                    DbgPrint("%08x %x %S\n", Privileges->Attributes, fResult, Name);

                } while (Privileges++, --PrivilegeCount);
            }
        }

    } while (dwError == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER);
}

void PrivTest()
{
    HANDLE hToken;

    if (OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES|TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
    {
        ULONG rcb;
        TOKEN_LINKED_TOKEN tlk;
        GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenLinkedToken, &tlk, sizeof(tlk), &rcb);
        CloseHandle(hToken);
        hToken = tlk.LinkedToken;

        DumpTokenPrivs(hToken);

        if (AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, TRUE, 0, 0, 0, 0) && GetLastError() == NOERROR)
        {
            DumpTokenPrivs(hToken);
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(hToken);
}
```

and output:

```
PrivilegeCount = 5
00000000 0 SeShutdownPrivilege
00000003 1 SeChangeNotifyPrivilege
00000000 0 SeUndockPrivilege
00000000 0 SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege
00000000 0 SeTimeZonePrivilege
PrivilegeCount = 5
00000000 0 SeShutdownPrivilege
00000001 0 SeChangeNotifyPrivilege
00000000 0 SeUndockPrivilege
00000000 0 SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege
00000000 0 SeTimeZonePrivilege
```

note that before call was

```
00000003 1 SeChangeNotifyPrivilege
```

was mean `SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT | SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED` attributes and `PrivilegeCheck` say that privilege is enabled.

after call was

```
00000001 0 SeChangeNotifyPrivilege
```

was mean `SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT` attributes and `PrivilegeCheck` say that privilege is disabled.